# Iterating over a list made up of distinct dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

Suppose I have a list that is made up of 3 dataframes, namely

```
lst = [df1,df2,df3]
```

where:

```
d1 = {'col1':['a','b','c','d','e']}
df1= pd.DataFrame(d1)
d2 = {'col1':['b','c','a','d','e']}
df2= pd.DataFrame(d2)
d3 = {'col1':['b','c','e','d','a']}
df3= pd.DataFrame(d3)
```

for each df in the `lst` I want to go through `col1` and find the rank of letter `a` and make a new dataframe from it, the output should look like:

```
  dataframe index  rank of a
0                0          0
1                1          2
2                2          4
```

namely, for `df1` letter `a` is on 0th index, for `df2` letter `a` is on 2nd index and so on. I wonder how one does this?

I tried doing:

```
ll = []
for i in lst:
    x = i[i['col1'].isin(['a'])]
    ll.append(x)
```

which extracts the ranks of `a`, I then tried

```
lll = []
for i in ll:
    x = ll[i][0]
    lll.append(x)
```

which doesn't work and I think my approach generally is not the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
pd.DataFrame({
    'df': range(len(lst)),
    'rank_of_a': [df['col1'].eq('a').idxmax() for df in lst]
})
```

Output:

```
   df  rank_of_a
0   0          0
1   1          2
2   2          4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just have a simple loop to go through your dfs:

```
rank_a = []
for df in lst:
    rank_a.append(df[df.col1 == "a"].index[0])

# rank_a = [0,2,4]
```

The idea is to filter for rows with "a" in col1 and use the index for rank. The code above assumes "a" will always be col1, so taking the first one.
As long as the dfs are having default index, it will be fine, if not you can always reset the index.

Then construct your final df:

```
rank_df = pd.DataFrame({
    "dataframe index": range(len(lst)),
    "rank of a": rank_a
})
```